# My App's XML TOO SLOW

Tags: android, xml

My XML is too slow, and I already found other's example but it didn't help mine.
See My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!--Preview Card-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/preview"
                    android:layout_width="380dp"
                    android:layout_height="213.75dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_ending"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/preview_bg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/bg_1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/preview_black"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:src="#000000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/preview_text1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/input_text"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <!--Empty Card-->
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/preview_empty"
                        android:layout_width="380dp"
                        android:layout_height="213.75dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_ending"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <!--Menu_1 Card-->
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/menu_1"
                        android:layout_width="380dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_ending"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/preview_empty"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <!--Text Font-->
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical">


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/text_font"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:text="@string/text_font"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

                                <Spinner
                                    android:id="@+id/dropdown_font"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/usual_margin"/>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/colortext"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_format_color_text"
                                        android:clickable="true"
                                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/boldtext"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_format_bold"
                                        android:clickable="true"
                                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/italictext"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_format_italic"
                                        android:clickable="true"
                                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
                                </LinearLayout>


                            </LinearLayout>
                            <!--Text Size-->
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_size"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usual_margin"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                            android:text="@string/text_size"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="16sp"/>
                                <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/usual_margin">
                                <SeekBar
                                    android:id="@+id/textsize_sb"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textsize_edit"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    android:progress="20"
                                    android:max="99"/>

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/textsize_edit"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                                    android:ems="2"
                                    android:maxLength="2"
                                    android:text="20"
                                    android:textAlignment="center"
                                    android:inputType="number" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <!--Input Text-->
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical">


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/input_text"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:text="@string/input_text"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/inputtext_edit"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                                    android:text="@string/input_text" />


                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <!--Menu_2 Card-->
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/menu_2"
                        android:layout_width="380dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_ending"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom= "80dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <!--Outer_Glow-->
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical">


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/text_glow"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usual_margin"
                                    android:text="@string/outer_glow"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:shadowRadius="20"
                                    android:shadowColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                    android:shadowDx="0"
                                    android:shadowDy="0"
                                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/usual_margin">
                                    <SeekBar
                                        android:id="@+id/glow_sb"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/glow_edit"
                                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                        android:progress="20"
                                        android:max="99"/>

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/glow_edit"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                                        android:ems="2"
                                        android:maxLength="2"
                                        android:text="20"
                                        android:textAlignment="center"
                                        android:inputType="number" />
                                </RelativeLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </ScrollView>

            <!--Preview Guideline    -->
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="253.75dp"
                android:src="#FAFAFA"/>

            <!--Save Button-->

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/saveexp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/usual_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/usual_margin"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_save"
                android:tint="#FFFFFF"
                app:fabSize="normal"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

That's it, and even it's hard to scroll it.

I already check java code, but it's not slow, but when I check xml code in temp app without java code, it is hard to scroll.

Is this structure bad?
Or why is it too slow...

What can I do? Thanks for your answering.

Comment: you have very huge tree of views, you should try to code xml with best practice to make it efficient, try reading [this](https://developer.android.com/training/best-ui.html)

Comment: 1. You have a ton of images that may or may not be appropiately scaled down to suit the device you are target 2. You are hardcoding dp sizes instead of using constraint layout or something that can scale to more than one display. Just my two cents.

Comment: Use method tracing in Android Studio to determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your help.I'll try it.

Comment: @Machinarius umm purpose of apps is to process image.

Comment: Thanks @AalapPatel